# ASPNET MVC DropDownListFor Reusing the same data list for two inputs results in unexpected selection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have created the following controller and view model. It allows for two user selections from the same select list.

### ViewModel and Controller Code

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Mvc5App.Controllers
{
    public class FormViewModel
    {
        public string UserSelection1 { get; set; }
        public string UserSelection2 { get; set; }

        public IList<SelectListItem> OptionsSelectList { get; set; }

        public FormViewModel()
        {
            this.OptionsSelectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }
    }

    public class FormController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var viewModel = new FormViewModel();

            viewModel.OptionsSelectList = new List<SelectListItem>() { 
                new SelectListItem {
                    Value = null,
                    Text = "- Select -",
                },
                new SelectListItem {
                    Value = "red",
                    Text = "Red",
                },
                new SelectListItem {
                    Value = "green",
                    Text = "Green",
                },
                new SelectListItem {
                    Value = "blue",
                    Text = "Blue",
                }
            }.ToArray();

            viewModel.UserSelection1 = "green";
            viewModel.UserSelection2 = null;

            return View(viewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

In the razor view you can see I'm using the same list for both DropDownFor helpers.

### Razor View

```
@model Mvc5App.Controllers.FormViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Form", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <br>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserSelection1)
    <br>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserSelection1, Model.OptionsSelectList)
    <br>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserSelection2)
    <br>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserSelection2, Model.OptionsSelectList)
    <br>
}
```

The problem is that if UserSelection1 already has a value, UserSelection2 will be set to that value if it is null.

Shouldn't a null value result in the selection of the first select list item?

Do I have to specifically set this to a empty string to avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DropDownListFor()` method internally builds a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in order to set the value of the `Selected` property based on the value of the property your binding to, but only if the value of the property your binding to is not `null`.

In the case of the first `DropDownListFor()` (for `UserSelection1`) the 3rd item will be `Selected = true"`. It also caches that collection in the `ViewDataDictionary`.

In the case of the second `DropDownListFor()` (for `UserSelection2`), the value of the property is `null`, so rather than building a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, the method uses the cached collection from `ViewData` which already has the 3rd item set as selected.

To see how this all works, you can view the [source code here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs).

You can make this work correctly by setting the value of `viewModel.UserSelection2 = "";`. Note also that if you were to swap the order of the `DropDownListFor()` methods, your would see the values your expecting (i.e "- Select -" would be chosen for `UserSelection2` and "Green" for `UserSelection1`)

A better alternative (that will display the correct results) would be to use

```
FormViewModel viewModel= new FormViewModel()
{
    UserSelection1 = "Green",
    OptionsSelectList = new SelectList(new string[]{ "Red", "Green", "Blue" }),
}
return View(viewModel);
```

and change the property to `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> OptionsSelectList { get; set; }`, and in the view use

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserSelection1, Model.OptionsSelectList, "- Select -")
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserSelection2, Model.OptionsSelectList, "- Select- ")
```

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour makes sense. Think about it ... you build your dropdowns from the same OptionSelectList. When the Form View loads, both your dropdowns are initially built with a selected value of green. The null value in UserSelection2 means that no value in the dropdown matches it so it will stay selected on the same value as the first.

To fix this, as you guess correctly you need to set the UserSelection2 value to empty string, which now matches the Please Select item so that one will be selected instead.

so, in your Index method in the Form controller just do this :

```
viewModel.UserSelection2 = "";
```

Comment: I like your thinking on this.. but the drop down doesn't have "green" selected set to true until the first DropDownListFor is called in the view. After that first one is set, all helpers that use that list will have selected = true with that value. I think your key point here is that **"no value in the dropdown matches"** ..in this case why would the helper decide that it should be set to the same value that happens to be set on the first input? Flip it around so that UserSelection1 is null and it works as I would expect.

Comment: It makes no sense because null integers will bind to empty string items in your dropdownlist but null strings won't.

Comment: wow, thank you for your comment 4 years after the answer lol. I don't even remember the question / answer :)

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who comes across this post later I found that just calling ToArray() method on the select list passed to the helper seems to fix this for all cases. Empty string or not:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PurchaseTypeId, PurchaseTypeSelectList.ToArray(), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

When adding form fields dynamically via ajax request/Json response that return razor template form partials, this was what I ended up using to handled int? as well as string type values in a drop down list. Otherwise when the drop down list is added to the dom (after page load) they render with selection of whatever happens to be selected.

Also had to add this for page load to the top of my editor templates:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    List<SelectListItem> PurchaseTypeSelectList = ViewBag.PurchaseTypeSelectList ?? new List<SelectListItem>();
    PurchaseTypeSelectList.ForEach(m => m.Selected = false);
}
```